# Force FBSDK ShareDialog React Native to use browser automatically

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

[React Native FBSDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) has a share dialog, but for some reason in the recent update if the iPhone has the Facebook app, then the prefilled content like

```
const shareLinkContent = {
  contentType: "link",
  contentTitle: this.props.name,
  contentUrl: this.props.link,
  imageUrl: this.props.pictureUrl,
  contentDescription: this.props.caption,
};
```

doesn't work when the app is installed, but the image, description and title DO show up when there is no FB app and the native app opens a browser. I want to force the sharedialog to use a browser every time. I know that RNFBSDK `ShareDialog` has a `setmode` function, but I can't find documentation on how to use it, and I couldn't infer it from the Objective-C documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The setmode function is a static function and can be used as `ShareDialog.setmode("webview")`, `ShareDialog.setmode("browser")`, or `ShareDialog.setmode("automatic")`

Comment: Doing this set the mode correctly but it disables all of my custom content fields and just grabs the metadata from the url provided. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Yes, had to drop the library because there was no way around it

Comment: Did you find something else to Share to Facebook or just stop using this library?

Answer (score 0):

@omriki, use

```
ShareDialog.setMode("web");
```

This will allow to use all the provided fields, including contentTitle and imageUrl.

Other modes - `native`, `feed`, `automatic`.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ShareDialog.Mode/